# Qualified access needed when inheriting from template

Tags: c++, templates

In a situation like this, why can't I access the base class member `x` unqualified in the `B1` case? Doesn't loook ambiguous to me…

```
template<class T>
struct A { T x; };

template<class T>
struct B1 : A<T> { T f() { return A<T>::x; } };

struct B2 : A<int> { int f() { return x; } };
```

Comment: didn't know of `using A<T>::x` before either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `x` is not dependent, it will be looked up in the
context where the template is defined.  In that context, the
compiler knows nothing of `T`, and cannot look in dependent base
classes.  How can it, for example, know anything of `A<T>` without knowing what `T` is.  (There could be a specialization of `A` for example, with completely different members.)

Comment: This doesn't explain *why* the compiler cannot see `x`. The base class isn't `T`, it's `A<T>`, and the definition of `A<T>` is already available when `B1` is defined. I know the language doesn't work that way, but the question, as I read it, is "why doesn't it?"

Comment: Actually, I think the question here is more about why it can't see `x` given that we *know* the base type is `A<int>`. No template arguments here at all.

Comment: The base class is dependent on `T`.  The compiler cannot see it until it knows what `T` is.  (What if `A<T>` is explicitly specialized for some types, for example?)

Comment: @sftrabbit When we know that the base class is `A<int>`, it can see `x`, and there is no problem.  When all that is known is that it is `A<T>`, then the compiler cannot know what `A<T>` contains until it knows what `T` is.

Comment: @JamesKanze Oh, I totally misread the question.

Comment: @JamesKanze Right. And that comment has the bit that should be part of the answer, I think, as that explains *why* the compiler cannot see `A<T>`'s definition even though it looks like it's right there.

Comment: But a specialized `A<int>` couldn't *remove* members? That's why I thought it was weird that I couldn't access `x` since we know it will be there for all `T`s.

Comment: @pascal When you specialize `A<int>`, you can do pretty much whatever you want.  If you want an example, look in the standard: `std::allocator<void>` has less than half the members of the generic `std::allocator<T>`.